# SQL Server : list by Nearest Birthday

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table `A` - column `B [DateTime]`

Need list users in that table, ordering at nearest birthday. Users who have already made birthday should be at the end of the list considering them for the following year.

```
select B from A (order by/where)?
```

Table Example

```
USER     DATE
MARCELO  1988-04-11
RICARDO  1965-12-30
WILSON   1977-02-20
PABLO    1985-01-10
JOHN     NULL
```

Expected Result

```
WILSON    20/02 (Month/Day)
MARCELO   11/04
RICARDO   30/12
PABLO     10/01
(JOHN NOT IN THE LIST)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(Name VARCHAR(100),Dob DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('Mark', '19961017'),('Josh', '19801119'),('Sam', '19700709'),
('Vicky', '19500210'),('Dom', '19890308'),('Paul', '19840401')
,('Nick', NULL)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT Name, CAST(MONTH(Dob) AS NVARCHAR(2)) 
              + '/' + CAST(DAY(Dob) AS NVARCHAR(2)) [Dob Month/Day]
FROM @TABLE
WHERE DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,Dob) - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE()) > 0
ORDER BY ABS(DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,Dob) - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE()))
```

**Result Set**

User vicky will be filtered out as birthday is gone.

```
╔══════╦═══════════════╗
║ Name ║ Dob Month/Day ║
╠══════╬═══════════════╣
║ Dom  ║ 3/8           ║
║ Paul ║ 4/1           ║
║ Sam  ║ 7/9           ║
║ Mark ║ 10/17         ║
║ Josh ║ 11/19         ║
╚══════╩═══════════════╝
```

Result set is ordered by who's birthday is next

Comment: SO when you run this on 12/31, what happens ?

Comment: While simple, you get no results when run on 12/31...for a person born on 1/1.

Comment: Exclude the where clause then because I thought you didn't want to show names who's bday is gone , on 31/12 everyone's bady is gone so it won't show any names , I'm on phone now so can't make any changes :s just keep the is not null in your where clause and the rest should be fine

Comment: //Users who have already made birthday should be at the end of the list considering them for the following year.//    I think that was a part of the original and edits of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, birthdate
from yourtable
where birthdate is not null
order by datepart(dy,dateadd(d,- DATEPART(dy, getdate()),birthdate ))
```

Comment: Hi podiluska, thank you for your time. I have edited my question with the expected result. You could redo the query to fit that condition?

Answer (score 1):

This solution:
"wraps around" for a full year.
and also allows a "how many months to project out" filter.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Employee') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #Employee
    end


    CREATE TABLE #Employee
    ( 
    SurrogateKeyIDENTITY int not null IDENTITY (1,1) , 
    NameOf varchar(12) not null , 
    BirthDate datetime not null
    )


    Insert into #Employee (NameOf, BirthDate)

    Select 'A', '01/01/1999'
    UNION ALL Select 'B', '01/16/1941'
    UNION ALL Select 'C', '01/29/1965'
    UNION ALL Select 'D', '02/13/1944'
    UNION ALL Select 'P', '02/14/1978'
    UNION ALL Select 'Q', '02/15/1984'
    UNION ALL Select 'R', '03/13/1948'
    UNION ALL Select 'S', '04/16/1983'
    UNION ALL Select 'T', '05/17/1953'
    UNION ALL Select 'U', '07/19/1959'
    UNION ALL Select 'V', '08/16/1959'
    UNION ALL Select 'W', '09/1/1959'
    UNION ALL Select 'X', '10/30/1959'
    UNION ALL Select 'Y', '11/16/1959'
    UNION ALL Select 'Z', '12/31/1972'


Declare @MyCURRENT_TIMESTAMP datetime
/* select @MyCURRENT_TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP */
select @MyCURRENT_TIMESTAMP = '02/14/2014'

Declare @NumberOfMonthsToGoOut int
select @NumberOfMonthsToGoOut = 12



;WITH myCalculationsCTE (NameOf, BirthDate, [NoYearBirthDate] , [NoYearCurrentDate] )
AS
(
    SELECT NameOf, BirthDate
    , DATEFROMPARTS( 1900 , MONTH(BirthDate), DAY (BirthDate)) [NoYearBirthDate]
    , DATEFROMPARTS( 1900 , MONTH(@MyCURRENT_TIMESTAMP), DAY (@MyCURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) [NoYearCurrentDate]
    FROM #Employee
    WHERE BirthDate IS NOT NULL
)
,
myCTE (NameOf, BirthDate, [NoYearBirthDate] , [NoYearCurrentDate] , DerivedMonthDiff)
AS
(
    SELECT NameOf, BirthDate
    , [NoYearBirthDate]
    , [NoYearCurrentDate]

    , [DerivedMonthDiff] = CASE 
        WHEN [NoYearBirthDate] >= [NoYearCurrentDate] 
            then DATEDIFF(m , [NoYearCurrentDate], [NoYearBirthDate] )  
        else 
            DATEDIFF(m , [NoYearCurrentDate], [NoYearBirthDate]) + 12 end

    FROM myCalculationsCTE
)

SELECT NameOf, BirthDate , [NoYearBirthDate] , [NoYearCurrentDate] 
    , DerivedMonthDiff
    , MONTH([NoYearBirthDate]) [Month]
    , DAY ([NoYearBirthDate]) [DayOf]

    FROM myCTE
    where [DerivedMonthDiff] <= @NumberOfMonthsToGoOut
    order by DerivedMonthDiff , MONTH([NoYearBirthDate]) , DAY ([NoYearBirthDate]) 

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Employee') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #Employee
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, our friend  M.Ali code worked smoothly.

Comment: That's because I wrote it before you posted sample ddl and sample data.  ...  Happy Valentine's Day.

Comment: I've revised my answer to get a full year's worth of birthdays, but in the proper order relative to today's date (02/14/2014 for my example)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, CAST(MONTH(BIRTHDAY) AS NVARCHAR(2)) 
              + '/' + CAST(DAY(BIRTHDAY) AS NVARCHAR(2)) [Dob Month/Day],DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,BIRTHDAY) as [dayofyear],
              case when (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,BIRTHDAY) - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE()) > 0)
              THEN
              DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,BIRTHDAY) - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE())
              ELSE
              DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,BIRTHDAY) + 365-DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE())
              END
              AS [DAYSTILLBURTHDAY]
FROM CONTACTS
WHERE BIRTHDAY <> '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY (case when (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,BIRTHDAY) - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE()) > 0)
              THEN
              DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,BIRTHDAY) - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE())
              ELSE
              DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,BIRTHDAY) + 365-DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE())
              END)
```

Comment: minor offset in [DAYSTILLBURTHDAY] (which was not part of the question), but a correct and complete list.